# How to change color button after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change color of button after clicking on it.I have tried with css and javascript but it doesn't work for me.
Here is the css code

```
<style>
.style {
    width: 115px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #8CC639;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #3071A9;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.style:hover {
background: blue;
}
 .style:active{
background: blue;

} */
.style:visited {
    color: red;
}

</style>
```

And here is the content in my jsp page:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnHousing').click(function() {
            //Now just reference this button and change CSS
            $(this).css('background-color','#f47121');
        });
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
        ui.panel.html(
        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
        }
        });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <div class="page">

    <fieldset>
    <form>

    <div align="center">
    <input  type = "button"
           value = "Throw"
         onclick = "javascript:location.href='throw.html';"
    />

    <span class="right">
    <input  type = "button" id="style"
           value = "User"
         onclick = "javascript:location.href='userAction.html'; "
    />
   </div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Create</a></li>
            <!--    <li><a href="user/viewLogin.html">Log In</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Update</a></li>

            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">
                <h1>Create</h1>

            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <h1>Update</h1>
            </div>


        </div>

      </form>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I want like stackoverflow button.When user click on button the color of button change after clicking on it.I have tried in some ways.Any code in css ,JQuery ore javascript?Thank you!

Comment: @hex494D49 That is wrong. CSS needs the `#` and 3 or 6 digits. Any other number will result in it not parsing.

Comment: Do you actually have a button with id=`btnHousing`?

Comment: Can't see any element with an id of `btnHousing` for the javascript to run, the CSS is also targeting elements with the `.style` class, and there is nothing in this HTML with a class of `style`, not to mention the fact that you seem to have a orphan comment close in there `*/`

Comment: It doesn't work my friend( hex494D49 )...I don't have a element with id "btnHousing",i want to use this late,it doesn't have an relationship..(PM 77-1)

Comment: @FationHadri, when directing a comment to someone on StackOverflow, make sure to put a `@` before their name. This will cause them to get a notification about your comment so they know it is there and can read it. For instance, in your previous comment you could have used `@hex494D49`. Also, there is no harm in it, but you don't need to do it for the owner of the Question or Answer you are commenting on, they get notifications for all comments on their post. In this case since your comment was about an answer not a comment on the question, the comment should have been on the answer.

Comment: Ok,thank you for information.I appreciate.. @Useless Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a class css selector rather than an id selector.

change the style to

```
#style
```

instead of

```
.style
```

or change the button to say

```
class="style"
```

Comment: This helps me but it doesn't keep color of button after clicking on it.Ane other sugesstions?Thanks...

Comment: Then I would follow your jquery idea but like this: `$('#style').on("click", function() { $(this).css('background-color','#f47121'); });`

Comment: it doesn't work,it is the same thing,only when we hover on a button,not after clicking.It looks like good but it doesnt work..

Comment: Your buttons look like they are taking you to different pages, this jquery code only works if it stays on the same page. Otherwise, you might have to look into storing the button's state in a session variable in jsp and load it back in when the page loads.

Comment: Yes,you are right,this button are take in diffrent jsp page.I will try in same jsp pages.Thanks you a lot :) @SnoApps

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('id-of-the-button').onclick = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
};
```

Or

```
<style type="text/css">
  .red {background-color: #ff0000;}
</style>  

document.getElementById('id-of-the-button').onclick = function(){
  this.className = 'red';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("purple");
  //the purple is a css class
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click handling seems to be ok.

It seems you just don't have a button with id "btnHousing".

A tested working example based on your code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="Housing"/>
<script>
    $('#btnHousing').click(function() {
        //Now just reference this button and change CSS
        $(this).css('background-color','#f47121');
    });
</script>
```